# Window opening with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, window.open

I would like to ask, if there is a way to open a new window in a web browser using the window.open() JavaScript command, but with animation? (with using JavaScript, query, etc.)

Comment: what type of animation? it is possible with JavaScript in the *opened* page
.

Comment: Please, on behalf of all users of the internet, don't do this. Just stick to animated GIFS and background music.

Answer (score 1):

Nope! Opening of new windows and tabs are controlled by the browser, but you can fake something similar with an element instead, and that could be animated.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example, if this is what you are looking for: [Animated Window Opener Script](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex8/window3.htm)

Comment: Wow that's so annoying it hurts.

Comment: @Andy, I know, but I tried to provide info on what was requested ;)

Comment: This is defenately an answer to the question, but to tell you the truth I wouldn't use it in my applications :)

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can't make it fade in or out since it's browser controlled. It really depends what kind of animation you are looking for. You could make it open on a starting position off-screen, and move it to the center